# LibAio: Why I can obtain data without calling io_getevents method?

Tags: c++, aio

I tried to read file contents using **Libaio**, but I found that even if I didn't call **io_getevents** method, the expected contents are obtained.

Is it **necessary** to call the **io_getevents** method after I call the **io_submit** method?

If yes, why this issue happened?

If no, when should I call io_getevents to the read result? Can I repead to call it **multi times**?

here is the demo code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libaio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#define error() printf("error [%s : %d]\n", __FILE__, __LINE__)
 
#define BUFF_SIZE 51
#define BUFF_CNT 50
#define READLEN 4194304
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open(__FILE__, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        error();
        return -1;
    }

    io_context_t ctx = 0;
    int err = io_setup(BUFF_CNT, &ctx);
    if (err != 0) {
        error();
        return -1;
    }

    struct iocb *io = (struct iocb *)malloc(sizeof(struct iocb));
    if (NULL == io) {
        printf("alloc struct iocb failed");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(io, 0x00, sizeof(io));

    char double_check_m_buf[READLEN];
    io_prep_pread(io, fd, double_check_m_buf, READLEN, 0);

    int rc = io_submit(ctx, 1, &io);
    if (rc < 0) {
        printf("aio send read one block failed");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("aio send read one block success, len: %d \n content: %s",strlen(double_check_m_buf), double_check_m_buf);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that may be going on here.

There are a bunch of cases where `io_submit` can't do asynchronous I/O.  When those happen, it falls back to synchronous I/O.  It's up to the caller to realize the requested I/O happened inline of the call.

In your case, you need to open the file with `O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT`.  That will likely do the trick, presuming your filesystem supports AIO.

If you open `__FILE__` with `O_DIRECT`, `io_submit` will bypass the kernel's buffer cache.  It may still complete rapidly.  Depending on what the underlying storage is, it may very well complete before you can inspect the buffer.  It's an off-chance, but still, it's possible.

The only way to be sure your I/O has completed is to call `io_getevents`.  That's the only way to retrieve the error if it fails.  Here, `__FILE__` is likely far shorter than 4 MiB, so you'll need the length of the read that's returned in that structure as well.

Comment: That's really helpful.  I tried to add O_DIRECT flag, it completed rapidby without call the io_getevents for `__FILE__`. When I used a longer file, the read length is shorter than 4M. After I use the io_getevents, It works as expected.